# How to run code on the main thread after async

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous

I have code that will only run on the main thread, but before that code can run, I need to initialize an object. Is there anyway I can force async code to run sync? The functions after the awaits are API calls, and therefore I cannot modify those directly.

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private MustBeInit mbi;

        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
            // async code that initializes mbi
            InitMbi(); 
            // mbi must be done at this point
            SomeCodeThatUsesMbi();
        }

        public async void InitMbi() {
            mbi = new MustBeInit();
            await mbi.DoSomethingAsync();
            await mbi.DoSomethingElseAsync();

            // is there any way i can run these two methods as not await and
            // run them synchronous?
        }

        public void SomeCodeThatUsesMbi() {
            DoSomethingWithMbi(mbi); // mbi cannot be null here
        }
    }
```

Comment: Await it, e.g. `await InitMbi()`, and the code after it will not run until it is complete.

Comment: @JohnWu Await cannot be run from a constructor, I will try to add await SomeCodeThatUsesMbi at the end of InitMbi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use the await in constructors, but you can put the whole thing into an async event handler subscribed to the `Loaded` event of the `Window`:

```
public MainWindow()
{
   this.Loaded += async (s, e) => 
   {
        await InitMbi(); 
        // mbi must be done at this point
        SomeCodeThatUsesMbi();
   };

   InitializeComponent();
}
```

And don't forget to change the return value of your `InitMbi()` to `Task`:

```
public async Task InitMbi()
```

Comment: Only saw your answer after submitting mine. This is how it should be done, Good answer +1.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> // is there any way i can run these two methods as not await and
> // run them synchronous?
> ```

Yes, just remove the `await` before the method call like:

```
public async void InitMbi() {
    mbi = new MustBeInit();
    mbi.DoSomethingAsync();
    mbi.DoSomethingElseAsync();

    // is there any way i can run these two methods as not await and
    // run them synchronous?
}
```

But be aware of the fact that this will block your main thread!

Comment: This won't block the caller thread at all, it'll start the async operations and will return immediatley to the caller without awaiting them.

Comment: Why do you think that this is the case? Calling a method marked with `async` without `await` will simply call it synchronously - so the calls will block until they are finished. And as `InitMbi` is called directly in the constructor it will block the constructor which is executed on the main thread - or I am missing something here? ;-)

Comment: It's not so simple, calling a method marked with `async` without `await` means that the rest of the code after the awaited call will not be queued for the completion, instead, they will be executed immedietly by the caller. So the constructor won't wait to the async calls to finish. To wait them synchronously you have to use the `.Wait()` or `.Result` of the `Task`.

Comment: That is not what the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/index) states ;-)
_An async method typically contains one or more occurrences of an await operator, but the absence of await expressions doesn’t cause a compiler error. If an async method doesn’t use an await operator to mark a suspension point, the method executes as a synchronous method does, despite the async modifier. The compiler issues a warning for such methods._

Comment: The documentation states the same, it executes the expressions after each other as a sync method (it won't queue the remaining stuff to execute after the completion), in case of an async call that means it will start the async method but it won't wait for the completion. Just wire up a new project and check it out. Also a compiler warning will show up to tell you that the caller won't wait for the non-awaited async method to finish.

Comment: Actually I did and the calls are blocking as I expected... although the mentioned warning is shown... I placed a breakpoint within the second method which will not be hit until the execution of the first one is done.

Comment: What was exactly in the async method?

Comment: Two methods, the same content. A for loop from 0 to `int.MaxValue` and within a call to `Console.WriteLine`. The only difference was the string within the `Console.WriteLine` so I can distinguish the result.

Comment: That means it's not a real async method even if you mark it as `async`. Try to call a `Task.Delay(100000)` without await, you'll se that the caller won't wait to finish that, it'll continue the execution of the remaining code.

Comment: Marking with `async` won't do anything. "Just" calling `Task.Delay()` won't also change nothing. But if you `await` an `async` method (like `Task.Delay()`) within the `async` method then the behaviour you described can be observed ;-)
I already gave you a +1 on your answer so there is no way to upvote again ;-)

Comment: I think there is some misunderstanding between us, i tried to describe the opposite behavior not what you mentioned that i did. Anyway i'd be happy to continue this discussion but i don't want to make this comment thread bigger so we can move it to chat if you'd like. I'm not hunting for upvotes, just wanted to point out that i do not agree.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182962/discussion-between-peter-csajtai-and-markus-safar).